# Split plot design with nested random effects and interactions between random effects

Tags: r, mixed-models, random-effects

I am trying to analyse a split plot design for a plant growth experiment with these variables:

- Biomass (dependent variable)
- Transect (sub plot factor with three levels)
- Treatment (main plot factor with two levels)
- Block (2 blocks in total, serving as replicates of the treatment)
- Location (multiple locations within each transect point)

I know what the random effect structure should look like. However, I can’t work out how to write this in R script. Could someone please help me? It’s probably very easy, but I have been looking for hours and hours and can’t find it.

Random effects should be:

- Block
- Interaction Block and Treatment
- Location nested within Transect
- (Location nested within Transect), interaction with Treatment

So perhaps something like:

```
(1|block) + (1|block*treatment) + (1|location:transect) +
  (1|(location:transect)*treatment)
```

Comment: A couple of clarifying questions: 1) Biomass is your dependent variable and not independent variable - Correct?  2) Is Location an independent variable or just repeated measurements within each Treatment-Transect combination.  3) If Location is an independent variable wouldn't this now be a split-split-plot design.  4) This questions is better asked on Cross validate as this is more of a stats question and not a programming question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1) Oops, Biomass is indeed the dependent variable. 2) Seeds were collected from plants along three independent transects and within each transects from different sublocations. 3) I know that the design is correct, since my professor told me so ;). 4) Thank you, I asked the question there

Comment: Please ave a look at https://stat.ethz.ch/~meier/teaching/anova/split-plot-designs.html and  `emmeans` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'll take a shot at this.

First: in 'modern' mixed model approaches it is not practical to treat a two-level categorical variable as random. In 'classical' method-of-moment/SSQ ratio approaches it works, although the power is terrible; in modern methods you will end up with 'singular models' (do a web search for "GLMM FAQ" or search here and on CrossValidated for more info). (The exception to this statement is if you go full-Bayesian and put regularizing priors on the random-effects parameters ...) Therefore, I'm going to take `block` as a fixed effect.

This would be (I think) your maximal model:

```
~ treatment*block + (treatment|transect/location)
```

- `treatment*block` (expands to `1 + block + treatment + block:treatment`: the baseline biomass (intercept) could differ between blocks, the treatments could differ, the treatment effect could differ between blocks
- `(treatment|transect/location)` (expands to `(1+treatment|transect) + (1+treatment|transect:location)`); the intercept and treatment effect vary among transects and among locations within transects. (This assumes that transects are uniquely coded between blocks, i.e. you don't have a transect `001` in both blocks, rather they are labeled something like `A001` and `B001`. If not, you need something like `(1+treatment|block:(transect/location))` ...

This also assumes you have multiple observations per transect/location/treatment combination. If not (if each treatment is observed only once per location), then the full interaction will be confounded with the residual variation and you instead need something like `(1+treatment|transect) + (1|transect:location)`.